# How to disable destroying of fragments in the new ViewPager2?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-viewpager2

In the `FragmentPagerAdapter` I can override `destroyItem` method and just remove line `super.destroyItem(container, position, object);`

```
    @Override
    public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
        //don't destory items after switching
        //super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
    }
```

Then fragments will no longer be deleted. But in the new `FragmentStateAdapter` I have not found the same method.

Comment: I don't think they intended for Fragments to not be detached. Although you could have also set the off page limit just like that on previous ViewPager too.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution. Just need add the one line to the your viewPager object:

```
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(numberFragmentsYouWantToKeep);
```

This will allow you to store the desired number of fragments in memory.